# How can I know a 2 last pressed key on a keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

Is it possible to know, what 2 last keys was pressed on keyboard?
How can I do it?
I need to compare this keys, and if they are the same - make some function.
As example, if someone press Enter - this is a first function, if after Enter he press a SPACE- this is a second function. If after the ENTER he press a Ctrl - this is a third function.
So, I hink that only onw way to do it - is make a 2 var with current and previous key value, and make a *IF ELSE IF* function
:-)
This is a way, how I get a current key value

```
$('#text').keydown(function(event) {
  $('#show').text(event.keyCode);
});
```

Or, the BETTER question! (I saw it right now)
Directly in this editor, after I press doublespace - it jump to anothe line in live-preview.
How it works? I'm not sure, but I thinks that I need is almost the same.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Answering your second question, this is [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with a *very* simple jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.keyWatcher = function() {
        return this.keydown(function(evt){
            var $this =  $(this);
           var prevEvt = $this.data('prevEvt');
            $this.trigger('multikeydown',[prevEvt,evt]);
            $this.data('prevEvt',evt);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This will raise a new event (`multikeydown`) whenever a `keydown` event is usually raised. This will either provide just the keydown event from the current key press, or if there is a previous one it will provide that too.

Usage could be something like:

```
$(document).keyWatcher().bind('multikeydown',function(evt,prevKey,currKey){
    alert('prevKey = ' + ((prevKey) ? String.fromCharCode(prevKey.keyCode) : '(none)')); 
   alert('currKey = ' + String.fromCharCode(currKey.keyCode));
});
```

Live example (press keys on the lower right hand pane in jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/9VMUy/1/

The event provided in `prevKey` and `currKey` parameters to the event handler contain the original `keydown` events, so you have full access to the `keyCode`, the `ctrlKey` and `shiftKey` properties etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think storing the last key pressed and checking both the old and new `keyCode` in the event handler is a good way to do this.

```
$('#text').keydown((function() {
    var lastKey = undefined;
    return function(event) {
        // here you have both the old and new keyCode
        lastKey = event.keyCode;
    };
})());
```

Also, the two spaces thing is [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) interpretation.

Comment: Hello,I'm not sure in your code - how can I display it? Or maybe not display, just compare: which var contains old or new value?

Comment: `var lastKey = undefined;` is the same as `var lastKey;`.

Comment: In place of my comment, the `lastKey` var contains the old value and `event.keyCode` contains the new ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best solution but see if you can use it or parts of it

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cP8Ud/9/)

```
var clicks = 0
$("#text").one("keypress", function () {
    clicks = 1;
    var KeyCode1 = event.keyCode;
    $('#result').text(KeyCode1);
    $("#text").one("keypress", function () {
        clicks = 2;
        var KeyCode2 = event.keyCode;
        $('#result').text(KeyCode1 + "\n" + KeyCode2);
    });
});
```

Comment: 1 minor problem - `event` is only available in IE, so this code doesnt work in FF. take the jQuery event passed in tto the handler to make it cross-browser. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cP8Ud/10/